# Octomap package not saving the map

Tags: navigation, octomap, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm using octomap package in Kinetic distro in combination with the gmapping package in order to perform 2D SLAM and build a 2D map and also a 3D map with Octomap. Both are working fine, the 3D map is being created correctly in rviz but when I try to save it i get the error of

```
Request to /octomap_full failes; trying again
```

In order to save it I'm using the command:

```
rosrun octomap_server octomap_saver -f name_of_map.bt
```

or

```
rosrun octomap_server octomap_saver -f name_of_map.ot
```

I get the same errors with the two different extensions. Any idea of what could be wrong here?

Thanks.

Andrés

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355618/octomap-package-not-saving-the-map/) by [iandresolares](https://answers.ros.org/users/56037/iandresolares/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iandresolares](https://answers.ros.org/users/56037/iandresolares/) on 2020-06-23**:
Don't know why the error doesn't appear in the question, it is this error: Request to /octomap_full failed; trying again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution here: https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping/issues/73

---

Originally posted by [iandresolares](https://answers.ros.org/users/56037/iandresolares/) with karma: 16 on 2020-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0